# Android Actionbar Up button versus system Back button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using the Actionbar and it's "up" button to return from a detail activity to the main activity, which works fine. Similarly, the user can press the system "back" button to return to the main activity.

In my main activity, in `onCreate()` data is downloaded from the internet to display upon app start. I noticed that when I use the Actionbar "up" button to go from detail to main activity, `onCreate()` is run, re-downloading the data. But `onCreate()` is not run when I use the system "back" button, therefore immediately showing the main activity view.

The code I use in the detail activity to implement the "up" button is:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
   case android.R.id.home:
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      startActivity(intent);
      return true;
```

I would like the "up" button to behave like the "back" button and not rerun `onCreate()`. But I'm unsure how to make this happen, or which code path the "back" button implements to return to the main activity.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to handle action bar up button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304483/proper-way-to-handle-action-bar-up-button)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Instead of starting a whole new activity simply finish the details activity you are in

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
   case android.R.id.home:
      finish();
      return true;
```

Then you will return to the previous activity on the activity stack (your main activity) and onCreate shouldn't be called

Comment: DOH! Now why didn't I think of that? I guess I'm trying to stick too close to the documentation.... Thanks!

Comment: This is **not** always the right solution. sometimes the activity start from another application and `up` should start the parent activity. more about it here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: Yes, but in google solution, `onCreate` called even when the activity in stack, do you know how to use mimic 'back' functionality when activity already exists, and create one otherwise?

Comment: `android.R.id.home` **home** is added in *api 11*! whats for 2.2 and above?

Comment: @shem know its late(may help some one, some day) use `android:launchMode="singleTop"` on your parentActivity!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar Thank you a lot! Maybe this answer does not match 100% to the question but it is exactly the elegant and simple way I was originally looking for!

Answer (score 10):

If you want Up to do exactly what Back does, you can do this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Note that the default implementation of `onBackPressed()` just calls `finish()`, but `onBackPressed` can be overridden.

Answer (score 8):

I think a better solution can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20306670/1435804).

Calling `finish()` works in specific situations but may not always produce the behavior described [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) e.g:

[image]

By calling

```
Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); 
NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
```

you'll return to the parent activity in the state in which you left it. If you have a flat app structure, it'll still act just like the Back button.

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer, because it will cover all possible cases, Thanks @Andy

Comment: This is the same as setting `singleTop` in the manifest, only programmatically. Good answer

Comment: Although your diagram makes a lot of sense, latest Gmail app as of 23rd August 2016 has the ActionBar/ ToolBar back arrow and the system back button behave all the same

Answer (score 0):

for a real "home" functionality , you should see the api demos ,under "App/Activity/Reorder Activities" .

the reason : what if you have something like this : activity1->activity2->activity3 , and now you wish to go to activity1 by pressing the home button on the action bar?

Comment: I only have two activities, the main and a detailed one. I always want to go back to the main activity from the detailed activity. I just like having the Actionbar home button as another (intuitive) method to go back to the "home" screen, in this case the main activity.

Comment: even so , you can reduce the time of opening the second activity by not closing it

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest way is to override the "getParentActivityIntent" method of the detail activity adding the flag "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP":

```
@Nullable
@Override
public Intent getParentActivityIntent() {
    Intent intent = super.getParentActivityIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        return super.getParentActivityIntent().addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    }
    return intent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution which can be in hand for somebody. I had the same double-behavior when user pressed Back and ActionbarBack buttons. I was fine with Back btn behaviour. I didn't want an activity to be recreated. So I overrode the method

```
     @Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

Works fine for me