# Activity With TabLayout Save State After New Activity Start

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, start-activity

I have an `Activity` that contains a `TabLayout` linked to a `ViewPager`. The `ViewPager` contains three fragments, and each fragment has a `RecyclerView` containing a list of articles. When you click on an a list item, it starts a new `Activity` with the full article text. After I start the new `Activity`, then press the back button to return to the first `Activity`, it starts with the first tab selected.

I would like to be able to start a new `Activity` from any tab, then when the back button is pressed, it goes back to the previous activity with the same tab selected. And preferably, maintain the state within the `RecyclerView` (i.e. how far it is scrolled down). How can I achieve this?

I have tried using `onSaveInstanceState` to save the `viewPager.getCurrentItem()`. It worked for when the device was rotated, but the saved instance state does not seem to be called after a new `Activity` is started.

---

The tabbed `Activity`:

```
public class ArticleActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.toolbar) Toolbar mToolbar;
    @Bind(R.id.content) ViewPager mViewPager;
    @Bind(R.id.tabs) TabLayout mTabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_article);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setupActionBar();

        FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new BaseFragmentPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),
                NewsFragment.newInstance();
                EventsFragment.newInstance();
                BulletinFragment.newInstance();
        );

        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    private void setupActionBar() {
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

And one of the fragments contained in the `ViewPager`:

```
public class NewsFragment extends BaseFragment implements
        Observer<DataResponse<NewsArticle>> {

    @BindDimen(R.dimen.divider_padding_start) float mDividerPadding;

    @Bind(R.id.recycler) RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    @Bind(R.id.progress) RecyclerView mProgressBar;
    @Bind(R.id.refresh_layout) SwipeRefreshLayout mRefreshLayout;

    @Inject RestService mRestService;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_refresh, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        mRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(
                ThemeUtil.getColorAttribute(getContext(), R.attr.colorAccent));
        mRefreshLayout.setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeColor(
                ThemeUtil.getColorAttribute(getContext(), R.attr.colorPrimary));
        mRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this::getArticles);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerDecoration(getContext(), mDividerPadding));

        getArticles();

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getTitle(Context context) {
        return context.getString(R.string.title_fragment_news);
    }

    @Override
    publiv void onCompleted() {
        mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable exception) {
        Timber.d(exception, "Failed to retrieve articles");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(DataResponse<NewsArticle> response) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        ArticleAdapter adapter = new ArticleAdapter(getContext(), response.data());
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this::onItemClick);
        mRecyclerView.swapAdapter(adapter, false);
    }

    private void getArticles() {
        mRestService.getNews().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(this);
    }

    public void onItemClick(Article article) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("article", article);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

---

I was curious, so I just tested it. The `Activity` doesn't actually get destroyed when I start the new `Activity`. It only gets destroyed (then recreated) after I press the back button. I don't understand why it would do that, if the `Activity` does not need to be destroyed when a new one starts, why would it need to be destroyed when it simply comes to the foreground?

I have another activity (my `SettingsActivity`) that does not have a parent `Activity`, and just calls `finish()` when the back button is pressed. If I start this `Activity` from my `ArticleActivity`, the `ArticleActivity` never gets destroyed, and saves its state perfectly.

Comment: `but the saved instance state does not seem to be called after a new Activity is started` use save preference instead.

Comment: @Sourabh Updated with code.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Really? I mean, I guess I could, but that seems like overkill... there has to be something simpler, no?

Comment: @Bryan No it is not a overkill also you are starting a new activity therefore all the saved instance would be destroyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer here: [ActionBar 'up' button destroys parent activity, 'back' does not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22780049/5115932)

And here: [How can I return to a parent activity correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15933890/5115932)

The parent (`ArticleActivity`) was getting destroyed after the *Back* button was pressed in the child `Activity` because that is the behavior of the "standard" launch mode. I set `android:launchMode="singleTop"` for the `ArticleActivity` in the manifest, which gives me the desired launch behavior. Now when *Back* is pressed in the child `Activity`, the parent is not recreated.